# Can access a object after postback - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am really confused with this behavior. Can someone explain this to me?

I have the following class structure:

```
public abstract BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  public List<string> listFieldMapper = new List<string>();
}

  public partial class Property : BaseUserControl
  {
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnInit(e);

      base.listFieldMapper.Add("test");
    }
  }
```

In a event handler of a button, (causes Postback), I can access the `base.listFieldMapper`

My understanding was that between postbacks, the state is not maintained, to be able to maintain the state, use the ViewState object. How is it that the list maintains the values?

On a side note, If I set the value of `base.listFieldMapper` after `OnInit` (Ex: Load), I have a null object after postback.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that when a button click calls a postback:

1. When the server is handling the request, an instance of the user control is being instantiated.
2. The server then calls the method that handles the button click.

When the page is requested (not handling a button click):

1. When the server is handling the request, an instance of the user control is being instantiated.
2. The server then calls the method that handles the Load event.

Comment: The OnLoad event gets called always (postback or not)

Answer (score 1):

The ViewState does not play a role in here. For it to track anything, you need to actually put something in it (most default properties do).

In your case, the sequence of events in the first case is (setting the list on init):

```
Control.OnInit -> add value
Page.OnInit    -> value present
Page.OnLoad    -> value present
Control.OnLoad -> value present
#PostBack
Control.OnInit -> add value
Page.OnInit    -> value present
Page.OnLoad    -> value present
Control.OnLoad -> value present
Button.OnClick -> value present
```

In the second case (setting the list on load):

```
Control.OnInit -> value absent
Page.OnInit    -> value absent
Page.OnLoad    -> value absent
Control.OnLoad -> add value
#PostBack
Control.OnInit -> value absent
Page.OnInit    -> value absent
Page.OnLoad    -> value absent
Control.OnLoad -> add value
Button.OnClick -> value present
```

And the listFieldMapper itself gets assigned in class constructor and will be non-null at any point in control's life cycle.

Comment: In 2nd case, the value is absent on Button.OnClick

Comment: Then something is missing. I copied your code and it works as advertised. Are you sure you are not doing something somewhere else?